# Is it possible to prevent popstate in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My website's navigation is using AJax. On the settings page, if the user has unsaved pages and clicks "Back", I want to be able to prevent the state from being popped.

Here's what I tried:

```
onpopstate=function(e){
    if(e.state){
        var event=jQuery.Event('beforeunloadajax');
        $(window).trigger(event);
        if(event.isDefaultPrevented()){
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

`e.preventDefault()` does not prevent the state from being popped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/popstate)

```
Cancelable: No
```